# obtain all the href from a specific author

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I'm trying to obtain all of the /pubmed/ numbers that link me to the abstract of articles that are from a specific author. The problem is that when I tried to do it,  I only obtain the same number over and over again until the for loop its over.

The href that I'm trying to obtain it should be taken from the output of `for line in lines` loop (the specific href is in the output example). That loop seems to work well but then, the `for abstract in abstracts` loop only repeat the same href.

Any suggestion or idea what I'm missing or doing wrong. I don't have much experience with bs4 so probably I'm not using the library very well.

```
#Obtain all the papers of a scientific author and write its abstract in a new file

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    import re

    import requests

    url="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=valvano"
    response = requests.get(url)



    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')


    lines = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "rslt"})

    authors= soup.find_all("p",{"class": "desc"})

    scientist=[]

    for author in authors:
            #print('\n', author.text)
        scientist.append(author.text)
    s=[]
    for i in scientist:
        L=i.split(',')
        s.append(L)          


    n=0

    for line in lines:

        if ' Valvano MA' in s[n] or 'Valvano MA' in s[n] :
            print('\n',line.text)
#part of one output:
<a **href="/pubmed/32146294"** ...


            found = soup.find("a",{"class": "status_icon nohighlight"})
            web_abstract='https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov{}'.format(found['href'])
            response0 = requests.get(web_abstract)
            sopa = BeautifulSoup(response0.content, 'lxml')
            abstracts = sopa.find("div",{"class": "abstr"})
            for abstract in abstracts:
                #print (abstract.text)


                print('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov{}'.format(found['href']))
#output: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170




            n=n+1

        else:

            n=n+1
#expected output:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/32146294
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/32064693
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31978399
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31919170
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31896348
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31866961
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31722994
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31350337
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31332863
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31233657
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31133642
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30913267
```

Comment: Can  you provide a representative sample of your expected output?

Comment: Can't you use the URL https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=valvano+MA and select all links?

Comment: @JackFleeting Let me edit the question with the excepted output

Comment: @Dan-Dev Yeah that will help but there are a lost of href in the web-page and still don't know hot to select the specific ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be that complicated. Just use:

```
ids = soup.select('dt + dd')
for i in ids:
    pmid = i.text
    print(f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/{pmid}')
```

Comment: This works great. But could you explain me a little bit what you did, because I remove the line in lines loop for this to works. Thank you!

Comment: @Nicolas - Glad it worked for you! Explanation is simple: you are looking for the PMID #. This number is always in the `text` of `<dd>` elements immediately following `<dt>` elements. No other info fits that description. So this selects all these elements and prints out the base url with that text.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to work on my HTML and bs4 knowledge. Very easy to follow this explanation

Answer (score 1):

Given that using the URL https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=valvano+MA returns the correct results you can use the following regex example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=valvano+MA"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('div.rprt p a'):
    if re.match('^/pubmed/[0-9]*$', a['href']) is not None:
        print('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov{}'.format(a['href']))
```

This will get all 20 results plus the Erratum for result 17. If you don't want this Erratum change line 10 to

```
    if re.match('^/pubmed/[0-9]*$', a['href']) is not None and a.get('ref') is not None:
```

Comment: Changing the web-page and using this code works. I didn't know that you coud do this:'^/pubmed/[0-9]*$', a['href']  thank you. Also the soup,select was a little bit difficult for me to understand it before this

Comment: The Erratum, do you mean the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable message, at the end of all the run ?

Comment: By the Erratum I meant the additional link in the 17th result  `PLoS One. 2018 Sep 4;13(9):e0203497. doi: 10.1371/journal.pone.0203497. eCollection 2018. Erratum in: PLoS One.` I'm not seeing a TypeError when I run this code maybe you changed it slightly?